# glfwSwapBuffers is slow

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, glfw

I have migrated my LWJGL application from LWJGL 2 to LWJGL 3, and the call of `glfwSwapBuffers()` is very slow (up to 20 ms per call), even if there is not a single render call in the game loop. I had this problem already when I tried to use `Display.update()`with LWJGL 2,  this method was slow too. I have measured the execution times with [JETM](http://jetm.void.fm). My operating system is Mac OS X 10.13.3 with an "Intel HD Graphics 500" as graphics card.

### The relevant code

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MainLoop_I();
    }

    private static final int START_WIDTH = 500;
    private static final int START_HEIGHT = 300;
    
    private long window;
    private GLFWErrorCallback errorCallback;

    
    private static GLCapabilities capabilities;
    
    public MainLoop_I() {        
        init();
        
        // configure time execution measurement library (JETM)
        BasicEtmConfigurator.configure();
        final EtmMonitor monitor = EtmManager.getEtmMonitor();
        monitor.start();
        
        loop();
        
        // print out results of JETM
        monitor.render(new SimpleTextRenderer());
        monitor.stop();
        
        glfwFreeCallbacks(window);
        glfwDestroyWindow(window);
        
        glfwTerminate();
        glfwSetErrorCallback(null).free();
        
        System.exit(0);
    }
    
    private void init() {
        glfwSetErrorCallback(errorCallback = GLFWErrorCallback.createPrint(System.err));
        System.out.println(glfwGetVersionString());
        if ( !glfwInit() ) throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to initialize GLFW");
        
        glfwDefaultWindowHints();
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW_TRUE);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_DEPTH_BITS, 24);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
        
        window = glfwCreateWindow(START_WIDTH, START_HEIGHT, "Game", NULL, NULL);
        if ( window == NULL ) throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create the GLFW window");
        
        
        
        glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
        glfwShowWindow(window);
        glfwFocusWindow(window);
        
        capabilities = GL.createCapabilities();
    }
    
    private void loop() {
        long lastFrameTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            
        
        glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        
        while(! glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
            glfwPollEvents();
            
            long thisFrameTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            float deltaSeconds = (thisFrameTime - lastFrameTime) / 1000f;
            lastFrameTime = thisFrameTime;
            

            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        
            EtmPoint point = EtmManager.getEtmMonitor().createPoint("MainLoop_I:loop");
            glfwSwapBuffers(window);
            point.collect();
            
        }
    }
```

What can be possible reasons for this very long execution time?

Comment: Thanks, by disabling v-sync i was able to reduce the execution time of `glSwapBuffers` to about 6 ms, but without any call of `glDraw...`. Do you know some other `gl...`-methods, which have a strong influence on the performance of `glSwapBuffers`?

Comment: @DasElias: you **should not** disable v-sync. `glfwSwapBuffers` isn't 'slow'---it rather **deliberately** waits for the monitor to synchronize to prevent tearing. You can't display more frames to the user than your monitor's refresh rate anyway, which is probably 60Hz, giving ~17ms between frames. You can't profile using your approach anyways, because OpenGL is pipelined and executed asynchronously. For profiling purposes use `GL_ARB_timer_query` to query the GPU times.

Comment: @DasElias this is actually expected behavior.  OpenGL drivers tend to bundle API calls under the hood and then send them to the GPU for execution in batches.  This actually reduces some communication overhead between CPU and GPU.  Every call in OpenGL is asynchronous, except for the frame buffer swap, which stalls the calling thread until all submitted functions have been executed.  Thus, the reason why glfwSwapBuffers seems to take so long.